# jQuery doesnt work in an external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm a beginner in JavaScript.

I have this simple HTML file where I tried to test jQuery with          `$("h1").hide()` and my problem is that the jQuery code works in the HTML but when I try to put this code in an external JavaScript file *testjs.js* and insert it via `script` tag to the `head`, it doesn't works anymore. Just to be clear, the external JavaScript file is recognized, for example when I put `document.write("third test")` in the external JS file it will show "third test".
Hope I've been clear

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
         <meta charset="utf-8"/>
         <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
         <script src="js/testjs.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <h1>first test</h1>
       <p>second test</p>

   <!-- this works only here but not in external js file
   <script>
    $("h1").hide();
   </script>
   -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you put it in that `testjs.js` file in that same order?

Comment: Put <script src="js/test.js"> line at the bottom of <body> tag

Comment: No need to add `<script>` tags in other file. And add script file at bottom

Comment: either move the file to the bottom before the `</body>` or wrap the code in `$(function() {  $("h1").hide(); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is regarding to document loading execution.  The execution of `$('h1').hide()` is happening just before the document is fully loaded.

### Three alternatives

- Put the script at the bottom of the body.

---

```
    <script src="js/testjs.js"></script>
</body>
```

- Bind the event `DOMContentLoaded` and put the logic of hiding within it.

---

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   $('h1').hide();
});
```

- Use the built-in function `ready` from jQuery

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h1').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It could be that the DOM has not loaded the h1 element you are trying to hide.  Try using this code in testjs.js.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h1').hide();
});
```

When manipulating elements you should wait for the document to fully load.